# Convert a mix of Pandas/List/Array to something Tensorflow will accept?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am using this to read some data into a character-level one-hot encoding. It's a bit inefficient but this is demonstration code so clarity is valued over performance:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

def onehot(str):
    chars = list(map(lambda c: max(0, ord(c) - 48), list(str)))
    twoDim = sess.run(tf.one_hot(chars, 122 - 48))
    # flatten the 2D array:
    return [item for sublist in twoDim for item in sublist]

import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
train_inputs = df['input'].map(onehot).values
train_labels = df['output'].map(onehot).values
```

The resulting arrays print as `[list([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...`

Later in the code, I feed these arrays into a TF cost optimization function:

`_,cost = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train_inputs, y_: train_labels})`

where I get this error:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Frankly I am baffled by Python's representation of array-like data structures, the nuances between list, array, ndarray, numpy array, pandas dataframe, etc, and I don't understand what I'm missing.

How can I convert the `train_*` variables to an array-like structure that Tensorflow will accept?

Please feel free to answer with a checklist that could help others in the future, or a point-answer that just fixes my code.

*SAMPLE DATA*

Here's what my input csv file looks like:

```
input,output
abc,def
ghi,jkl
123,456
```

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: Sample data has been added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a call to `.tolist()` was enough to make Tensorflow accept the data:

```
train_inputs = df['input'].map(onehot).values.tolist()
train_labels = df['output'].map(onehot).values.tolist()
```

Tensorflow likes native arrays (represented using square brackets), and `tolist()` outputs native arrays, which are at least for this use-case, indistinguishable from `list()`.